# The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to delete a principal from the database but can't because it owns a schema. When I go to edit the user, however, the box to uncheck schemae is blue and unremovable.  How can I remove the principal from these schemas?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try the T-SQL to do this:

```
alter authorization
on schema::YourSchemaName
to dbo
go

drop user TheUserYouWantToDelete
go
```

You can't drop a principal that is a schema owner, so the `ALTER AUTHORZATION` changes the owned schema (I used `YourSchemaName`, but obviously substitute that with the owned schema in your database) to `dbo` (likewise, you can change ownership to whatever principal you need in your environment).  That will allow you to drop the previously-schema-owning user (for example purposes I used `TheUserYouWantToDelete`, but that'll be the now non-owner that you want to drop).

Comment: Okay, so this worked.  I'm a little confused as to why, however.   Why do I need to authorize the schema to another schema?  Maybe I need to review schemas...

Comment: @rsteckly Simplified, authorization = ownership. If you could delete the user that owns the schema, the schema wouldn't be valid, because the owner no longer exists. Imagine you could delete a customer who has placed an order. What does the CustomerID in the Orders table mean if there is no longer a Customer that it points to? Where should I ship the order?

Comment: Sorry, my example wasn't well explained.  We're not changing authorization to the `dbo` schema, we're changing authorization to the `dbo` principal.  That could have been any database principal.

Answer (score 48):

The T-SQL way works.  Thanks to 
http://zarez.net/?p=179
I found the SSMS way to do this (UI).

To change the schema owner from Sql Server Management Studio:

```
Expand your database -> Security -> Schemas
```

In the Object Explorer Details you can see a list of the schemas and the owners:

[image]

If you don't know what schema(s) the User owns, check the properties of the User.

[image]

Open up the properties of the schema that the User owns, and click "Search" to find a new owner.  If you don't know the new owner, you can "Browse" for one.

```
Properites -> Search -> Browse
```

and you can change the schema owner to dbo (or whoever is most appropriate).

[image]

Comment: T-SQL way is much better and flexible. Doing it through GUI has (is) always a pain !

Comment: I'm all for the T-SQL way, also because it can be used in scripts.

Comment: Note: F7 is the shortcut to display details if it isn't coming up

Answer (score 4):

It has been already [showed before](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19458/22336) that before dropping a user you need to reassign any schema it might own to `dbo` as per the example below:

```
alter authorization
on schema::YourSchemaName_Ownedby_TheUserYouWantToDelete
to dbo
go

drop user TheUserYouWantToDelete
go
```

However, sometimes the user you want to delete has more than one schema assigned to it.
You can find all the schemas owned by a particular user by using this script:

```
  SELECT S.* 
       ,[the schema ownwer]=dp.name
       ,dp.type_desc
FROM SYS.schemas S
INNER JOIN SYS.database_principals dp
       ON S.principal_id = dp.principal_id
```

[image]

Just a note:
In the example above the user `mathura\radhe` has several schemas including `db_owner` although this user is NOT the [db owner](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18610/22336) of this database in particular.

Below is a partial view of the script I use to get ready to drop a user in a database.

There are other things to consider - as they're not included in this script:

1. getting all the permissions of this user, before you drop it - just in case you need to rollback - for that I recommend [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/150175/22336) or [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123843/22336)
2. I have not checked about the roles assigned to this user - just because I never had this problem so far
3. I am not scripting the login and user creation - you might need this before you drop it
4. Always check that you are in the right server and right database before running this script

   ```
     SELECT   THE_SERVER      = @@SERVERNAME
         ,THE_DATABASE    = QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())     
         ,THE_USER        = QUOTENAME(dp.name)
         ,IS_ORPHAN       = dp.IS_ORPHAN
         ,[DROP_USER]     = 
          'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + 
          '; DROP USER [' + dp.name           
           + '] '      
         ,[RESET_SCHEMA]  = 
         'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + 
         ';' + dp.THE_SCHEMAS  +  
         ';'       
         ,[RESET_ROLE]    = 
         'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + 
         '; ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON Role::[' + dp.name           
         + ']  TO [dbo]'

   FROM
     (SELECT
     [NAME]               = dp.name
    ,IS_ORPHAN            = CASE WHEN (sp.sid is null  
                            AND c.sid is null   
                            AND a.sid is null) 
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ,THE_SCHEMAS          = STUFF((   
                SELECT N';'+ N'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::' + 
                CAST (QUOTENAME(s.name) as sysname) + SPACE(1) + 'TO [dbo]'
                                       FROM sys.schemas s
                                       WHERE s.principal_id = dp.principal_id
                                       FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

   FROM sys.database_principals dp
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals sp
                 ON dp.sid = sp.sid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.certificates c
                 ON dp.sid = c.sid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.asymmetric_keys a
                 ON dp.sid = a.sid

   WHERE 1=1
    AND dp.type in ('U', 'S', 'C', 'K') 
    AND dp.principal_id > 4 
           /*0..4 are system users which will be ignored*/
    AND NOT (dp.type = 'S' 
            AND LEN(dp.sid) = 28) 
           /*to filter out the valid db users without login*/) dp    
    WHERE dp.name = 'mathura\radhe'
   ```

[image]

then I copy the script generated on the RESET_SCHEMA column:

```
USE [sgdragnet];
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[mathura\radhe] TO [dbo];
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[radhe] TO [dbo];
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[mathura] TO [dbo];
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[KRISHNA] TO [dbo];
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[db_owner] TO [dbo];
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[db_securityadmin] TO [dbo];
```

and the other columns also contain significant info.
hope this helps