# Trying to add permission to a Role is failing

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, permissions

I am trying to add a role into Create and Restore permissions and After researching online, it sounds like it should be as easy as using the GRANT statement. So far so good. However, my simple grant statement which looks like following:

```
GRANT CREATE, Restore ON dbo TO EventmanagerAdmin
```

Throws following error :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE'.
```

I wish I had more information to debug but that is all it says. Some more details in environment and background:

- I am using SSMS 2012
- The role does exist with Execute permission on this DB
- I used script from [List all permissions for a given role?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36618/list-all-permissions-for-a-given-role) to confirm that what permissions does the role have

Is there anything that I might be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to note is that `RESTORE` is a command, not really a permission that can be granted.  Which is why your `GRANT` failed.

In the SQL Server Books Online at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx has pretty much said the same thing from SQL Server 2000 until now, namely:

**RESTORE** permissions default to members of the `sysadmin` and `dbcreator` fixed
server roles and the owner (`dbo`) of the database ... members of the `db_owner`
fixed database role **do not have `RESTORE`** permissions.

If the `dbo`, **not** `db_owner`, seems confusing it is like this.   One login owns the database, it may be `sa` or `MyDomain\MyLogin`.   That login maps to the dbo user and should have rights to restore the database.   Inside the
database, many users may be in the `db_owner` role, but since those are inside
the database to be restored, they do not get the `RESTORE` permission.

So, you can make logins members of the `dbcreator` fixed server role or you
can make one user the owner of a database and he should then be able to do a
restore of that database.

To test the consequences I created a login `TestLogin` that is **not** a `sysadmin` for these tests.

**TEST 1:** Granted `TestLogin` the `dbcreator` server role and the `public` role
in MyDatabase.  (It is necessary that `TestLogin` have *some* rights inside
the database to be restored.)

`RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase` ... was successful.

**NOTE:**  If the restored database did not already have `TestLogin` as a user,
`TestLogin` lost access to the database once the restore was complete since
the `sysusers` data was restored with the contents from the backup.  So,
`TestLogin` needs to exist in the source backup if this user is to retain some internal rights after the restore.

**TEST 2:** Revoked `TestLogin` from the `dbcreator` server role and the `public`role in `MyDatabase`.  Made `TestLogin` the owner of the database.

```
USE MyDatabase
exec sp_changedbowner 'TestLogin'
```

`RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase ...` was successful.

In other words, `dbcreator` can create NEW databases, but can only restore a
database where it is already a user **and still retain rights to that database**.  Hope that this helps you decide what to do.