# Get list of permisison for a SQL role

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, role

I have a role named `db_executor` and need to find out what permissions it has on what objects. I found [List all permissions for a given role?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36618/list-all-permissions-for-a-given-role) but the only solution that remotely works is:

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS 'DBName'
      ,p.[name] AS 'PrincipalName'
      ,p.[type_desc] AS 'PrincipalType'
      ,p2.[name] AS 'GrantedBy'
      ,dbp.[permission_name]
      ,dbp.[state_desc]
      ,so.[Name] AS 'ObjectName'
      ,so.[type_desc] AS 'ObjectType'
  FROM [sys].[database_permissions] dbp LEFT JOIN [sys].[objects] so
    ON dbp.[major_id] = so.[object_id] LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] p
    ON dbp.[grantee_principal_id] = p.[principal_id] LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] p2
    ON dbp.[grantor_principal_id] = p2.[principal_id]

WHERE p.[name] = 'db_executor'
```

The problem is that the `ObjectName` and `ObjectType` is `NULL`. So while I know it only has the `EXECUTE` permission in a state of `GRANT` I don't know to what object(s) that applies to. Is there a better way to get this list or how can I modify this code to list the Object(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is missing a left join to `sys.types` to grab table type information, which also requires execute permissions to use (alternatively join `sys.table_types`, you'll get the same data). Try the following:

```
SELECT  DB_NAME() AS 'DBName' ,
    p.[name] AS 'PrincipalName' ,
    p.[type_desc] AS 'PrincipalType' ,
    p2.[name] AS 'GrantedBy' ,
    dbp.[permission_name] ,
    dbp.[state_desc] ,
    CASE WHEN [dbp].[class_desc] = 'DATABASE' THEN 'DATABASE'
         ELSE COALESCE(so.[name], t.name)
    END AS 'ObjectName' ,
    CASE WHEN [dbp].[class_desc] = 'DATABASE' THEN 'DATABASE'
         ELSE COALESCE(so.[type_desc], N'TYPE')
    END AS 'ObjectType' 
FROM    [sys].[database_permissions] dbp
        LEFT JOIN [sys].[all_objects] so ON dbp.[major_id] = so.[object_id]
        LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] p ON dbp.[grantee_principal_id] = p.[principal_id]
        LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] p2 ON dbp.[grantor_principal_id] = p2.[principal_id]
        LEFT JOIN [sys].[types] t ON dbp.major_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE   p.[name] = 'db_executor';
```

Comment: That returns a Objectype (Table?_TYPE) but still null for the ObjectName

Comment: How many rows are you getting out of this? And what is the class_desc from database_permissions for the null objects?

Comment: I am getting a single row returned and the `class_desc` is "DATABASE". Also, sorry for the delay, I was not working over the weekend.

Comment: I've updated the script to include the database scoped permission.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Below code gives all the roles

```
SELECT  DB_NAME() AS 'DBName' ,
        p.[name] AS 'PrincipalName' ,
        p.[type_desc] AS 'PrincipalType' ,
        p2.[name] AS 'GrantedBy' ,
        dbp.[permission_name] ,
        dbp.[state_desc] ,
        so.[name] AS 'ObjectName' ,
        so.[type_desc] AS 'ObjectType'
        --, so.*
FROM    [sys].[database_permissions] dbp
        LEFT JOIN [sys].[objects] so ON dbp.[major_id] = so.[object_id]
        LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] p ON dbp.[grantee_principal_id] = p.[principal_id]
        LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] p2 ON dbp.[grantor_principal_id] = p2.[principal_id]
```

I only found ObjectName, ObjectType only for **public** role

[image]

And following values

[image]

Comment: This returns 47759 rows, way to many to dig though. I only need it for my single row as defined in the OP.

Comment: HI Matthew, i dont have db_executor in my database, but another script below by Nic gives 1855

Comment: Which column should I be doing a where clause in your code to narrow it down? Your count would be different then mine since we have different DBs but my results is almost 50k, to many to dig though looking for a single role

Comment: I tried on `p.type_dec` but it did not return anything, so either I tried the wrong column or this is not pulling all roles.