# Can I trust the effective permissions of default database roles?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions, role

I've granted membership in the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles for some testing being performed by a specific user.

Looking at the names of each role, I know what the roles do. However, I want to *see* where the permissions were assigned just to better understand.

To my surprise I see a blank slate for the `db_datareader` schema for that database. I go onto read [Understanding SQL Server fixed database roles](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1900/understanding-sql-server-fixed-database-roles/) and from there I know why I cannot see anything in that properties dialog:

> The catch with this role is that the permission is implicit. That means if you query sys.database_permissions, you will not see any permission granted, either to the db_datareader role or directly to the user. Therefore, if you need to audit for everyone who has SELECT access to particular tables in a database, you'll have to query the membership of this group via the use of sp_helprolemember

I was aware of querying the roles which obviously works fine. So I thought this was *perhaps* a limitation of the GUI. I liked the permissions script from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44339/118303) and gave that a run. However, upon execution, that returns `NULL` for `permissiontype` and `permissionstate` which is consistent with the above quote.

All that said, are these pre-canned roles infallible? Can I assume that no one can mess around with the implicit nature of their respective permissions i.e you can't remove `select` rights from `db_datareader` behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question:

> are these pre-canned roles infallible? Can I assume that no one can mess around with the implicit nature of their respective permissions i.e you can't remove select rights from db_datareader behind the scenes?

According to the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx#Anchor_0), fixed database roles, including `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` cannot be modified:

> These roles exist in all databases. The permissions assigned to the fixed-database roles cannot be changed.

Therefore, you can rest-assured assignment of rights via these roles are fixed and cannot be modified.

Granting membership in `db_datareader` is the equivalent of doing `GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE::[db-name] TO [principal];`

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I just tried in a test database (SQL Server 2012):

```
GRANT EXEC ON SCHEMA::dbo TO db_datareader
```

...And the response I got:

```
Msg 4617, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot grant, deny or revoke permissions to or from special roles.
```

So I'm assuming you're reasonably safe. Of course, that's not to say you couldn't do something wacky like having a stored procedure testing for membership in those roles, and implementing its own security functionality based on the results.