# Scipt User roles and permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, users, access-control

I am having issues with the user accounts in SQL Server v 11.0.6020. I need to run a script that will allow for the copy of the principal user account: 'TrainID1' and all of the user rights and permissions so that when I get the other users logged in, they can access the DB's and run the applications that connect to the SQL DB's.
So I have the user: 'TrainID1', and that user connects to the SQL DB: 'TrainID_01' DB, so I need to have TrainID2 to 42 user accounts allowed in SQL Security for all of the other Data Bases like: TrainID_02, TrainID_03 and so on...

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you have a look at the procedure [sp_dbpermissions](https://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_dbpermissions/) by Kenneth Fisher.

I have been using it and it allows you to list all the permissions of a particular user in a database, and gives you all the scripts to copy all those permissions and apply them on a different database.

In case you want to apply them on a different server as well, that is fine too, but don't forget to create the server login first.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this via the [dbatools powershell module](http://www.dbatools.io).

There is an [Export-SqlLogin cmdlet](https://dbatools.io/functions/export-sqllogin/) that will do nearly exactly what you describe. From the documentation, this cmdlet will:

> Exports Windows and SQL Logins to a T-SQL file...with SIDs, passwords,
>   defaultdb, server roles & securables, database permissions &
>   securables, login attributes (enforce password policy, expiration,
>   etc).

If you need to replicate the exported login N times, you could modify the exported T-SQL script. However, you likely need to consider that all N can't be created with the same SID, so you may wish to simply remove the SID when you rename/clone the login.