# In the context of another principal what permissions hinge on the identity of the database owner?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, windows, access-control

By "database owner", here, I mean the principal whose SID is [`sys.databases`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).`owner_sid`.

[This answer to the question of best practices for database ownership](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/256950/70613) includes the following:

> The answer here comes down to priorities: Convenience *xor* Security? Pick one.
>
> One issue is that the database owner is used to determine permissions for certain operations. The sa account, by its very nature, is not restricted from anything (outside of maybe placing restrictions on itself, but now we're just being silly). I'm not sure what that list of operations is, but using a low-privileged SQL Server login as the owner is definitely one way that people discover what those operations are ;-) (hence why so many people prefer to use sa, even if it is a poor choice; more on that in a moment).

This suggests that the permissions granted to the database owner are factored into permissions checks during operations invoked in the security context of other principals.  This sounds reasonable and I can imagine a circumstance where changing the database ownership resolved some permissions issue, but I have not seen that play out first-hand.

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18616/70613) seems to support this suggestion:

> the most important thing: the database owner has important side effects, specifically the EXECUTE AS context. This later problem is what burns most users. Since Service Broker makes extensive use of EXECUTE AS (the message delivery has an implicit EXECUTE AS context, as well as queue activation that has an explicit one) is usually Service Broker users that discover this problem first.

This suggests that `EXECUTE AS context` could lead to unintended escalation of privileges to those of the database owner.

[Microsoft's "Summary of the Permission Check Algorithm"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#_algorithm) does not, however, seem to mentioned the database owner:

> **Security context**
>
> This is the group of principals that contribute permissions to the access check. These are permissions that are related to the current login or user, unless the security context was changed to another login or user by using the EXECUTE AS statement. The security context includes the following principals:
>
> - The login
> - The user
> - Role memberships
> - Windows group memberships
> - If module signing is being used, any login or user account for the certificate used to sign the module that the user is currently executing, and the associated role memberships of that principal.

[Microsoft's Chart of SQL Server Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#chart-of-sql-server-permissions) also doesn't seem to mention `owner_sid` (although a lot seems to hinge on the db_owner *role*, but that is a different matter).

Furthermore, [Microsoft's "Understanding Execution Context"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187096(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) does not seem to make any special mention of the database owner.

This raises the following questions:

1. What permissions, if any, hinge on `sys.databases.owner_sid`?
2. Are there operations that SQL Server invokes using `sys.databases.owner_sid` to which the "SQL Server Permission Check Algorithm" does not apply?
3. Does `EXECUTE AS ... context` somehow allow a normal user to inherit the permissions of `sys.databases.owner_sid`?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I had meant to write a blog post where I explain this in detail (more than is appropriate here), with example scripts, etc, but just haven't had the time. But, rather than have this remain unanswered until I have time to write that post (test scripts are done but need to be cleaned up), I will post the basic info here and come back later to adjust once that post is published.</sub>

---

There are two related scenarios that I know of that are dependent on the permissions of the database owner:

1. Trying to access instance-level resources, or another database, while using either impersonation or an App Role
2. Trying to obtain either `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` or `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission (instance-level permissions) while using unsigned SQLCLR assemblies (*and* using either SQL Server 2005 - 2016 *or* SQL Server >= 2017 and *not* using the [horrible "trusted assemblies" hack](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/28/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-4-trusted-assemblies-the-disappointment/))

Both scenarios are related by being times when enabling `TRUSTWORTHY` is required. And, both are also scenarios that can [avoid the evil `TRUSTWORTHY ON`](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/) by implementing the far better approach of [Module Signing](https://modulesigning.info/).

### Scenario #1

is very similar to, but still not the same as, actually accessing instance-level resources or another database under impersonation. There is a lot of overlap as they are two parts of the same functionality. I would guess that most of the time impersonation is being used to become the `dbo` user via the `EXECUTE AS` clause of a `CREATE {module}` statement, specifying either `OWNER` or `N'dbo'`. In that case it's very difficult to separate the indirect requirement, but impersonating a non-`dbo` user makes it clear.

When impersonating a user (we're assuming a non-`dbo` user), in order to access instance-level resources or another database, not only does the current database need to be marked as `TRUSTWORTHY`, but the login associated with the `dbo` user of the current database (i.e. same SID between the login and `dbo`) needs to have the `AUTHENTICATE SERVER` permission. This is not well known, which is likely why so many people simply resort to having `sa` own the database: it has all permissions. Many people, I'm sure, who already have their DBs owned by `sa` might never even know that this is a potential problem because the condition was already satisfied when they enabled `TRUSTWORTHY` in order to get the impersonation working.

**EXAMPLE:**

Setup:

- There is a database, `[TestDB]`, that has `TRUSTWORTHY` set to `ON`.
- Database `[TestDB]` is owned by login `O` (this means that the `dbo` user in `[TestDB]` has the same SID as login `O`). `O` is *not* a member of `sysadmin` nor has `CONTROL SERVER` permission, or any high-level permission.
- The application connects as login `A` that has an associated user `A` in database `[TestDB]`. Login `A` is *not* a member of `sysadmin` nor has `CONTROL SERVER` permission, or any high-level permission.
- There is also a login, `P`, that has an associated user `P` in database `[TestDB]`. Login `P` is *not* a member of `sysadmin` nor has `CONTROL SERVER`, *but* does have the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission.
- There is a stored procedure in `[TestDB]` named `dbo.ViewAllSessionInfo` that selects from `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_requests`, and is *not* filtered to only display the row for the current login or SPID / `session_id`.

Behavior:

1. Login `A` (the app login) can execute `dbo.ViewAllSessionInfo`, but only gets 1 row returned, the row for the current session.
2. The stored procedure is altered to contain the `EXECUTE AS N'P'` clause (`P` has the required permission).
3. Login `A` executes `dbo.ViewAllSessionInfo`, but still only gets 1 row returned, the row for the current session (even though the stored procedure is now executing as `P`, and `P` does have `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission, *and* the database has `TRUSTWORTHY` enabled).
4. Login `O` is then granted the `AUTHENTICATE SERVER` permission.
5. *Now*, when login `A` executes `dbo.ViewAllSessionInfo`, rows for *all* sessions are returned (even though the only new permission added was granted to `O`, and *not* to either `A` or even to `P`).

### Scenario #2

occurs when creating or altering an assembly, or even trying to use any code (stored procedure, trigger, functions, or type) from within an assembly that has been marked as either `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE`. Additionally, starting in SQL Server 2017, if you keep the "security" setting of "CLR strict security" enabled (the default), then even assemblies marked as `SAFE` need to meet this requirement (again, we are assuming that neither module signing nor "trusted assemblies" is being used). In this case, assuming that a non-`dbo` account is attempting one of those actions, the login associated with the `dbo` user of the current database (i.e. same SID between the login and `dbo`) needs to have either the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` or `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission. This is more widely known than Scenario #1 (due to an error message that provides this information), yet many people simply resort to having `sa` own the database (again, everything "magically" works). Many people, I'm sure, who already have their DBs owned by `sa` might never even know that this is a potential problem because the condition was already satisfied when they enabled `TRUSTWORTHY` in order to get the operation working.

**EXAMPLE:**

Setup:

- There is a database, `[TestDB]`, that has `TRUSTWORTHY` set to `OFF` (different than test case for Scenario #1).
- Database `[TestDB]` is owned by login `O` (this means that the `dbo` user in `[TestDB]` has the same SID as login `O`). `O` is *not* a member of `sysadmin` nor has `CONTROL SERVER` permission, or any high-level permission.
- The application connects as login `A` that has an associated user `A` in database `[TestDB]`. Login `A` is *not* a member of `sysadmin` nor has `CONTROL SERVER` permission, or any high-level permission.
- There is also a SQLCLR assembly, `C`, in database `[TestDB]`. Assembly `C` has a `PERMISSION_SET` of `UNSAFE`.
- There is a stored procedure in `[TestDB]` named `dbo.DoUnsafeStuff` that is really a .NET method in assembly `C`.

Behavior:

1. Login `A` (the app login) can execute `dbo.DoUnsafeStuff`, but gets a security error.
2. Database `[TestDB]` is altered to set `TRUSTWORTHY` to `ON`.
3. Login `A` can execute `dbo.DoUnsafeStuff`, but still gets a security error.
4. Login `O` is then granted the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission.
5. *Now*, when login `A` executes `dbo.DoUnsafeStuff`, the stored procedure operates as expected, without the security error (even though the only new permission added was granted to `O`, and *not* to `A`).

### In both scenarios,

the required permission is not required for the principal performing the action. It's more of a gate-keeper to determine if the requested action is allowed to be performed by any principal within that database.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this.  I’m not completely confident that I can correctly interpret this summary.  I’m hoping that your more detailed post will include test scripts so that I can experiment with these scenarios first-hand.

Comment: @alx9r Ok, I will let you know when I publish it (might be a week or two). For now, I have added a simplified step-by-step look at each scenario to hopefully communicate the concept more clearly.